# Spring TCP Client Server max connections

Tags: spring-integration

Trying to build a TCP server using Spring Integration in which keeps connections may run into thousands at any point in time. Key concerns are regarding

1. Max no. of concurrent client connections that can be managed as session would be live for a long period of time.
2. What is advise in case connections exceed limit specified in (1).

Something along the lines of a cluster of servers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's no mechanism to limit the number of connections allowed. You can, however, limit the workload by using fixed thread pools. You could also use an `ApplicationListener` to get `TcpConnectionOpenEvent`s and immediately close the socket if your limit is exceeded (perhaps sending some error to the client first).

Of course you can have a cluster, together with some kind of load balancer.

Comment: Requirements state that (a) Session would need to be maintained between clients and server, unless it is closed by either party or it times out, and (b) no. of connections could run into ten thousands. Would it be possible to handle requirement (a) using non blocking approach and keep all sessions alive? Should one-thread-per-connection approach be considered for this requirement?

Comment: (a) is satisfied regardless of the threading (thread per connection or using NIO). (b) implies you should use NIO because thread per connection is not practical for so many connections.

Comment: Are there any unit tests specific to SpringIP where thread per connection or NIO can be tested?

Comment: There are [many tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp). What, specifically, are you looking for?